# Is there an algorithm to "simplify" a dependency graph?

Tags: graph-algorithm, simplify

My problem is very simple but I don't really know its name and therefore, it's hard to find a solution by myself :
How to simplify a dependency graph like (where `->` means depends):

> A -> B -> C & A -> C

to

```
A -> B -> C
```

Comment: Those are different graphs.  A depends on C and B "A->B->C" isn't a "simplification"

Comment: The first graph is : D(A) = {B, C}, D(B) = {C}, D(C) = {}, so in this case, the graph  D(A) = {B}, D(B) = {C}, D(C) = {} is equivalent because C must be done before B anyway.

Comment: @Peter the dependencies are transitive, I think, which is why for the questioners purposes they are the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for [transitive reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction).

For a discussion of algorithms, see [Transitive Closure and Reduction](http://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/TDBAfl/VT06/algorithms/BOOK/BOOK4/NODE163.HTM).